# Blank page when use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today i started to use Sublime Text 3 with LiveReload, but i cannot normally developing with it, because always when i start to write code in JavaScript file i get blank page with just one - parameter from my JavaScript file.. Everything else is ignoring..

So i made youtube video for show how it looks like.
http://youtu.be/a_CEqNSc82M

That is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">But43 trej gfdf</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">in my case i need</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some words different</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">length</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">some words different</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">length</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your problem is not jQuery but the line `document.write(....`

Comment: So, i just tried to output parameter to my page, what can you make suggest for replacing that line? Thank you.

Comment: Adeneo already gave the correct answer I believe.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` strangely enough overwrites the entire document when used like that, that's why it's blank ?

Also, writing a script tag inside a script tag like that doesn't work, you should be using the following method to add script tags to the head section :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var head    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script  = document.createElement('script');

    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src  = 'http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1';

    head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry i do not well in english. Do you recommend to replace the standard code from LiveReload for that one?

Comment: ..also remember to look at `window.location.protocol`.

Comment: @tanotify - I have no idea how liveReload works, but any plugin that recommends using document.write is not something I would use ?